# Easy SQL problem i can't solve without IF, ELSE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause

Here's the deal

I have two tables.
The first one is called "boys"

```
**ID    bestFriend  notBestFriend**
boy1    f123    f123 /
boy2    f456    f789 /
boy3    (null)  f852 /
```

the second one is called "friends"

```
**friendID  fullName**
f123    Tim /
f456    Ron /
f789    Bud /
f852    Jack
```

my need is to write an SQL query that give me back for each boy the full name of the best friend (if present) otherwise the notBestFriend fullName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `left join` twice:

```
select b.*, coalesce(f1.fullname, f2.fullname) friend_fullname
from boys b
left join friends f1 on f1.friendid = b.bestfriend
left join friends f2 on f2.friendid = b.notbestfriend
```

Comment: thanks but this doens't give back the notBestFriend's full name if the bestFriend is null

Comment: @DavideCasolari: it sure does. See this db fiddle for your reference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b3321f88daa553da812e747eae604251

Comment: now it works perfectly, the previous version didn't. anyway ty so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE WHEN` statement in your `ON` clause, that specifies which column to use for the `JOIN` depending on whether column "bestfriend" is `NULL` or not:

```
SELECT ID, fullName as friendName
  FROM t1
  JOIN t2
    ON (CASE WHEN (t1.bestFriend IS NOT NULL 
                   AND t1.bestFriend = t2.friendID) THEN 1
             WHEN (t1.bestFriend IS NULL 
                   AND t1.notBestFriend = t2.friendID) THEN 1
        END) = 1
;
```

This will produce the following result for the example data in the question:

```
ID     friendName 
=================
boy1   Tim
boy2   Ron
boy3   Jack
```